# Runtime Error While Using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, solver

I'm attempting to use solver to fit a regression line on excel. But I am encountering difficulty as the message "Sub or function not defined" prompts up when I try to call the Macro.

My ultimate goal is to create a loop for the solver down a column.

```
Public Sub SolverTry()

SolverReset
SolverAdd CellRef:="$B$5", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$C$5", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
SolverOk SetCell:="$A$5", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:="$B$5:$C$5"
SolverSolve userFinish:=True

End Sub
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: You should be posting your SolverReset, SolverAss, SolverOk and SolverSolve Macros

Comment: @Noldor: SolverReset, SolverAdd, SolverOk and SolverSolve are not users macros. They're methods defined in the solver add-in.

Comment: Have you tried this; http://peltiertech.com/Excel/SolverVBA.html

Answer (score 2):

You should add reference to solver. In VBA go to tools-->references-->check solver.